# CSS: control direction of table growth when font size changes

Tags: css, jqplot

We have a charting package we use (jqPlot) and it creates a legend
box that is rendered as a table. My users asked for the ability to make the legend larger or
smaller, so I gave them some buttons that when clicked change the font
size of the items in the legend and that works fine.

Issue is that as the legend box gets larger or smaller it's 'anchored'
at its upper right corner. and grows to the left and shrinks to the
right. My users want it to be anchored on the upper left corner and
grow to the right and shrink to the left. I'm not sure how to do that.
I didn't create the page, the charting package did, but I can
manipulate the CSS in jQuery.

Here is all the CSS associated with the legend. I copied this from the
chrome developer's tools.

```
element.style {
position: absolute;
margin-top: 0px;
z-index: 3;
right: 0px;
top: 9px;
font-size: 11.8px;
}

table.jqplot-table-legend {
max-height: 450px;
padding-right: 20px;
overflow: auto;
display: block;
}

table.jqplot-table-legend,table.jqplot-cursor-legend {
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

table.jqplot-table-legend {
margin-bottom: 12px;
margin-left: 12px;
margin-right: 12px;
}

user agent stylesheet table {
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 2px;
}

Inherited from
div#chart_0.jqplot-target
.jqplot-target {
position: relative;
color: #666666;
font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

Inherited from
body.ng-scope
body {
margin: 0px 0px 3em 0px;
background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: I can't be sure w/o seeing more code, but I think it might just be as simple as removing that `right: 0px;` (or changing its value to `auto`) and using `left: 0px;` instead.

Comment: Tried that, it moved the legend box all the way over to the left side of the page. I want the legend box in the same place, but anchored at its top left corner instead of its top right.

Comment: What currently determines where its top left corner position is? If it's a parent element, try adding `position: relative;` to the parent so that the legend box's position is done relative to the parent. If it's some fixed width, you can either set that width as the `left` value, or use `margin-left` or some such. If it's something else, well, lemme know and we can go from there.

Comment: The top left is relative to the chart the legend is associated with. I was able to determine where that should be and then set the `left` value of the legend to that and it works like a charm! Thanks so much!